# apache chainsaw v2 gets: bind exception or connection lost! :: invalid stream header: 3c3f786d

Tags: java, java.util.logging, apache-chainsaw

i wrote a log server that eats the stuff coming from a bunch of sockethandlers on other devices and writes it to a log file which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
<record>
  <date>2016-05-15T06:40:03</date>
  ...
</record>
...
```

i am new to chainsaw.

chainsaw can open these files using: load java util file.

if i add a simple receiver for port 4445, i get a bind exception.

if i add a simple receiver for port 4560, i get the connection lost.

i do not have any config files and am unsure about how to write one.

if i can get the simple receiver to work, can chainsaw rollover the log files and separate the log files by the device they are coming from?

thanks

edit 1: looks like that reveiver may use: org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLDecoder, which may not be the correct one. this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033309/how-do-i-get-apache-chainsaw-oeprating-based-on-the-following-chainsaw-config-xm) suggests: org.apache.log4j.xml.UtilLoggingXMLDecoder. manually trying this does not seem to work.

edit 2: thanks to scott deboy on the log4j mailing list, this config file worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration >
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
<plugin name="XMLSocketReceiver" class="org.apache.log4j.net.XMLSocketReceiver">
      <param name="decoder" value="org.apache.log4j.xml.UtilLoggingXMLDecoder"/>
      <param name="Port" value="2222"/>
   </plugin>
<root>
  <priority value="debug"/>
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

edit 3: added a rollover:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration >
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
<plugin name="XMLSocketReceiver" class="org.apache.log4j.net.XMLSocketReceiver">
      <param name="decoder" value="org.apache.log4j.xml.UtilLoggingXMLDecoder"/>
      <param name="Port" value="2222"/>
   </plugin>
<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
      <param name="File" value="sample.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
      </layout>
   </appender>
<root>
  <priority value="debug"/>
  <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" /> 
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

this seems to work, but all of the chainsaw logging (as well as my stuff) is in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Chainsaw can parse log files matching the log4j xml format, or regular text log files with a consistent log format via VFSLogFilePatternReceiver, but not your own xml format.

Comment: my log files are in standard jdk util format, you can see the dtd in the files. chainsaw eats these just fine when i manually open them with: load java util file from the menu.